# Problem with IE8 when i am using windows user control in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

please help me..
I used windows user control in asp.net website. it is running in IE7 but not in IE8
PLease sugeest me how to run my website in IE8 ???

I used code like that

```
<object  id="OperationsControl" classid="clock_control.dll#clock_control.UserControl1" >
</object>
```

Comment: You will have to supply more details for us. There is nothing in your questin that can make start to figure out what is going wrong with your site.

Comment: Who uses IE? I feel bad for you.

Comment: @The Rook, Like it or not, lots of people use IE,... it does have the biggest market share after all!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AskIE blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/askie/archive/2009/05/22/net-control-no-longer-loads-in-ie8-in-internet-zone.aspx), .net user controls are not supported in IE8 *in the Internet zone*, which is why it isn't loading:

> If you want to allow loading .NET
>   controls for any web site that is
>   impacted by this change, you can add
>   it to the trusted sites zone. But
>   please note that the site that needs
>   to be added is that of the control and
>   not that of the page.

The page linked aso contains further instructions on how to mitigate this issue.